# lead object synchronization issue in marketing cloud

Tags: integration, marketing-cloud-connect, marketing-cloud

I have done all the steps needed to synchronize salesforce sales cloud objects to the marketing cloud and i can synchronize all the objects except lead. when I try to sync lead the cogwheel just keeps on rotating and doesn't get synchronized and after couple of hours, it vanishes. I have synced all my other objects

Comment: Best to open a support case

Comment: I tried syncing few fields first and it did work for me added some fields later